# How to find which checkstyle version gradle is using?

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle

In my gradle file I have:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

I'm trying to create my own checkstyle rules. For this reason I have added a dependency to my gradle file.

```
dependencies {
     checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.2'
}
```

I am trying to extend "Check" class of checkstyle. But there are a lot of version of checkstyle and I dont know which one is used by gradle.

How can I find the exact version number of checkstyle which gradle is using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of right now, least attractive first:

- You can look into the Gradle [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.4.0/subprojects/code-quality/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/CheckstylePlugin.java#L37).
- You can check the [Checkstyle Compatibility Matrix](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html?hl=L[g];L8.12;L6.19;L5.9;L5.7-L5.5) (column L, yellow cells).
  Both say that from Gradle 3.3 onwards, the default Checkstyle version is 6.19; before, it was 5.9. Only Gradle versions prior to 2.4 used even older versions of Checkstyle.
- **But** the recommended way is to *choose* the Checkstyle version explicitly, by specifying it in your build.gradle file:

  ```
  checkstyle {
      configFile file('your/checkstyle.xml');
      toolVersion '8.2';    // your choice here
  }
  ```

  This is better than relying on the default version, because you can use much newer versions of Checkstyle, and your Checkstyle setup won't break when you update Gradle.

Comment: how do you ensure that which one is specifically being used in your project?

Comment: How do you know all available toolVersions?

Comment: `toolVersion` is the Checkstyle version, choose any: https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html @BakulG

Answer (score 6):

You can check the current value of `checkstyle.toolVersion` by writing this in your build.gradle file and reloading your gradle project

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

println checkstyle.toolVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide a better solution, and you can refer the to the examples of configuration file from checkstyle source codes without worrying about compatibility.

Simply run `gradle dependencies | grep checkstyle`

Then get corresponding checkstyle sources here to refer the configuration samples: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases

Comment: Why downvoted? This doesn't require refreshing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

with out-of-box `apply plugin: 'checkstyle'`, the checkstyle would use [v6.19](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/code-quality/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/CheckstylePlugin.java#L37).

Downloaded dependencies:

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/6.19/checkstyle-6.19.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.5.3/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-master/4.5.3/antlr4-master-4.5.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1/commons-cli-1.3.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/41/commons-parent-41.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/6.19/checkstyle-6.19.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.5.3/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar
```

after `dependencies { checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.2' }`, the downloaded dependency list:

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/8.2/checkstyle-8.2.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7/antlr4-runtime-4.7.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-master/4.7/antlr4-master-4.7.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.8.0-4/Saxon-HE-9.8.0-4.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7/antlr4-runtime-4.7.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.8.0-4/Saxon-HE-9.8.0-4.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/8.2/checkstyle-8.2.jar
```