# Checkstyle, Unable to create Root Module

Tags: android, checkstyle

I'm trying to configure Checkstyle in the project. I've added:

```
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
    checkstyle {
        // assign the latest checkstyle version explicitly
        // default version is very old, likes 5.9
        toolVersion = '8.6'
        // checkstyle.xml copy from:
        // https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/checkstyle-8.6/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml
        // the version should be as same as plugin version
        configFile = rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    }
    task Checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
        source 'src/main/java'
        include '**/*.java'
        exclude '**/gen/**'
        exclude '**/R.java'
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'

        // empty classpath
        classpath = rootProject.files()
    }
```

to my root gradle file in `allprojects`.

But when I run `./gradlew checkstyle`

I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:Checkstyle'.
> Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/user/Development/project/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.
```

Even the file with rules is located in specified dir.

Comment: It's probably the `classpath` line, which you should remove. But even better, organize your code so that your real code (that you want checked) is in a *SourceSet* (e.g. `main`). Then you would not need to create a task at all, because the Checkstyle plugin already creates perfectly fine tasks for you.

Comment: Removing the classpath gives a different error:
> No value has been specified for property 'classpath'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem was that it couldn't find rules file. So I changed:

```
configFile = rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
```

to:

```
configFile = file("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
```

and now it pick up it correctly.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. The app's checkstyle.xml was in a subdirectory. Once I moved it back to /config/checkstyle/ in the root directory of the project, it worked.

Comment: (spelling mistake) change to checkstyle.xml from ckeckstyle.xml in your answer.

Answer (score 34):

This happened to me when I updated Android Gradle Plugin to 3.3.0

Please run this:

> ./gradlew checkstyle --stacktrace

Probably you will need to check your **checkstyle.xml** config file.

I needed to move those two tags:

```
 <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>

        <!--Enable usage SUPPRESS CHECKSTYLE comment-->
        <module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
            <property name="commentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE IGNORE"/>
            <property name="checkFormat" value=".*"/>
            <property name="influenceFormat" value="0"/>
        </module>
```

inside

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
```

tag

Also I needed to remove:

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean Gradle or Android Gradle Plugin? My Gradle version was above 4.

Comment: Android Gradle Plugin

Comment: I had this issue before 3.3.0 was released and this was an root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328412/1048418

Comment: Yes, it is so very helpful to see not just where gradle and its plugin failed but where checkstyle failed.  For example "...CheckstyleException...illegal value ... for property 'headerFile' .

Comment: For those that are using Java 11 or higher and `Unable to find: suppressions.xml`: Add the `${config_loc}` variable in front of the suppressions' file path in your Checkstyle config, e.g.: `<property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml"/>`. See [https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8286](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8286) for more.

Answer (score 22):

From the release notes of [version 8.24](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html#Release_8.24):

> Change LineLength Check parent from TreeWalker to Checker.

So I had to move

`<module name="LineLength">`

from inside

`<module name="TreeWalker">`

to inside

`<module name="Checker">`

Comment: I had a project in java 8 and gradle 4.4, wanted to change to java 11 and gradle 6, and so this was the configuration that helped me compile :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I got this error when `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` contained a reference to a non-existent file. In my case, via:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="config/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/> <!-- Oops: No such file! -->
</module>
```

Creating the file `config/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml` fixed the problem.

If it helps, its contents (with same header as `checkstyle.xml`) was:

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="/generated/" checks="\w+"/>
    <suppress files="/test/" checks="\w+"/>
</suppressions>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this question asked in different dimensions (asked both on SO and github) and here is the summary of what I found.

I am assuming the location of `checkstyle.xml` is not the issue here. Before walking through this solution, I will suggest you look through the other answers on how to resolve that. The fastest way to verify is to put this print statement in one of your tasks and run it (the task)

`println(file("${rootDir.projectDir}/path/to/checkstyle.xml"))`

Make sure the path it prints out in the console is correct/valid. If it is the correct path but you still see the error, then you have a different issue; Proceed to the scenarios below:

- If you added checkstyle plugin in Gradle like this (I am using Gradle >= 4.0):

```
plugins {
id 'checkstyle'
}
```

The default checkstyle version will be used for that version of Gradle. There is another Compatibility Matrix for Gradle Version vs default Check Style plugin version [HERE](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html?hl=L[g];L8.12;L6.19;L5.9;L5.7-L5.5)

- If you would like to specify the `checkstyle.xml` to be used by the plugin, you need to bear this in mind - There is a matrix of the plugin version vs compatible `checkstyle.xml` version. For google check style the best way I found is to check the plugin release. For example, if I want to use version `8.2` in my project, the `build.gradle` entry for it will look like this:

```
plugins {
id 'checkstyle'
}

checkstyle {
  project.ext.checkstyleVersion = '8.20'
}
```

This will use automatically use(pull) the `checkstyle.xml` compatible with that version specified (i.e. 8.20).

- If you would like to customize (add/remove) some check style rules, I would advice you start with(edit) the compatible version.
  To know the `checkstyle.xml` version that will be compatible with this plugin version, go to [Google Checkstyle releases](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases) on Github  and download the  [8.20 release](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases/tag/checkstyle-8.20) zip or tar.
  After unpacking it, locate the google (or sun) checkstyle xml in `src/main/resources/` directory. After customizing the xml as needed, your `build.gradle` entry will look like this

```
plugins {
id 'checkstyle'
}

checkstyle {
  project.ext.checkstyleVersion = '8.20'
  configFile = file("${rootDir.projectDir}/path/to/google_checks.xml")
}
```

Hopefully, you will stop seeing that error.

Comment: Good answer. 

Note that incase you don't specify the version like 8.20 above, you can find out the version of checkstyle your gradle plugin is using, see :https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492946/2200690, and then follow the rest of the steps above.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was failing because of java version mismatch.

I was running `java 11` but in `build.gradle` sourceCompatibility = 1.8

Once I switched to java 1.8 it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens whenever the config file could not be read. Are you sure you have a `/Users/user/Development/project/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` file ?

Answer (score 2):

I was also having similar issue and same exception message. The following steps solved my problem:

Updated tool version to 8.16. Before I had 8.1
I used 'configDir' instead of 'configFile' property.

```
configDir = file("$rootProject.projectDir/etc/checkstyle")
```

Before it was:

```
configFile = file("$rootProject.projectDir/etc/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
```

Additionally, I had a 'reportDir' property which was also changed to point the directory instead of file.

```
reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/checkstyle")
```

Before it was:

```
reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
```

I am using JDK 11 and it worked with it.

Comment: I used `configDir = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/checkstyle")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and I basically used the answer by @Bohemian. checkStyle could not find a file so I force-fed it waht it wanted. In my case, the root cause was that the gradle plugin for NetBeans does not propagate all "environment" variables correctly, so a reference to `${basedir}/config/checkstyle/import-control.xml` failed. When `checkStyle` is running in NetBeans, `${basedir}` is set to `$USER_HOME`, instead of the root of the project. As a workaround, I copied the required files into my home directory, and that allows `checkStyle` to run correctly.
Ugly, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may also be due to you using obsolete apis in your checkstyle configuration. See this links [here](https://github.com/mikedw/android_tools/issues/1) and [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3671).

Answer (score 0):

```
in build.gradle add this.

plugins {
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '4.7.3'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion '10.7.0'
    configFile file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    ignoreFailures false
}

**your checkstyle.xml should like like this as structure is changed in latest checkstyle version.**


https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
    Checkstyle configuration that checks the Google coding conventions from Google Java Style
    that can be found at https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

    Checkstyle is very configurable. Be sure to read the documentation at
    http://checkstyle.org (or in your downloaded distribution).

    To completely disable a check, just comment it out or delete it from the file.
    To suppress certain violations please review suppression filters.

    Authors: Max Vetrenko, Ruslan Diachenko, Roman Ivanov.
 -->

<module name="Checker">
  <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/>

  <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>

  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
  <!-- Excludes all 'module-info.java' files              -->
  <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_filefilters.html -->
  <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
  </module>
  <!-- https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter -->
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.google.suppressionfilter.config}"
           default="checkstyle-suppressions.xml" />
    <property name="optional" value="true"/>
  </module>

  <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
  <!-- See http://checkstyle.org/config_whitespace.html -->
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
  </module>

  <module name="LineLength">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    <property name="max" value="100"/>
    <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
  </module>

  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
    <module name="IllegalTokenText">
      <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
      <property name="format"
               value="\\u00(09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
      <property name="message"
               value="Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or Unicode escaped value."/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
      <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowByTailComment" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowNonPrintableEscapes" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
    <module name="NoLineWrap">
      <property name="tokens" value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="option" value="TEXT"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_WHILE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="ANNOTATION_DEF, CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                    INTERFACE_DEF, LAMBDA, LITERAL_CASE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DEFAULT,
                    LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF,
                    LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_DEF,
                    OBJBLOCK, STATIC_INIT, RECORD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="id" value="RightCurlySame"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE,
                    LITERAL_DO"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
      <property name="option" value="alone"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT,
                    INSTANCE_INIT, ANNOTATION_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                    COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressionXpathSingleFilter">
      <!-- suppresion is required till https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7541 -->
      <property name="id" value="RightCurlyAlone"/>
      <property name="query" value="//RCURLY[parent::SLIST[count(./*)=1]
                                     or preceding-sibling::*[last()][self::LCURLY]]"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="COMMA, SEMI, TYPECAST, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_RETURN,
                    LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_FINALLY, DO_WHILE, ELLIPSIS,
                    LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LAMBDA,
                    LITERAL_YIELD, LITERAL_CASE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowEmptyLambdas" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowEmptyTypes" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowEmptyLoops" value="true"/>
      <property name="ignoreEnhancedForColon" value="false"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="ASSIGN, BAND, BAND_ASSIGN, BOR, BOR_ASSIGN, BSR, BSR_ASSIGN, BXOR,
                    BXOR_ASSIGN, COLON, DIV, DIV_ASSIGN, DO_WHILE, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAMBDA, LAND,
                    LCURLY, LE, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY,
                    LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_RETURN, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,
                    LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, LOR, LT, MINUS, MINUS_ASSIGN, MOD, MOD_ASSIGN,
                    NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, QUESTION, RCURLY, SL, SLIST, SL_ASSIGN, SR,
                    SR_ASSIGN, STAR, STAR_ASSIGN, LITERAL_ASSERT, TYPE_EXTENSION_AND"/>
      <message key="ws.notFollowed"
              value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not followed by whitespace. Empty blocks
               may only be represented as '{}' when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)"/>
      <message key="ws.notPreceded"
              value="WhitespaceAround: ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="FallThrough"/>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                    STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                    COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
      <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapDot"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="DOT"/>
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapComma"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="COMMA"/>
      <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <!-- ELLIPSIS is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/259 -->
      <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapEllipsis"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ELLIPSIS"/>
      <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <!-- ARRAY_DECLARATOR is EOL until https://github.com/google/styleguide/issues/258 -->
      <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapArrayDeclarator"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_DECLARATOR"/>
      <property name="option" value="EOL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapMethodRef"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_REF"/>
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
    </module>
    <module name="PackageName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Package name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypeName">
      <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                    ANNOTATION_DEF, RECORD_DEF"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Member name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="LambdaParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Lambda parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="CatchParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Catch parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Local variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="PatternVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Pattern variable name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Class type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="RecordComponentName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
               value="Record component name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="RecordTypeParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
               value="Record type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Method type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName">
      <property name="format" value="(^[A-Z][0-9]?)$|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[T]$)"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Interface type name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
      <message key="ws.followed"
             value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is followed by whitespace."/>
      <message key="ws.preceded"
             value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is preceded with whitespace."/>
      <message key="ws.illegalFollow"
             value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' should followed by whitespace."/>
      <message key="ws.notPreceded"
             value="GenericWhitespace ''{0}'' is not preceded with whitespace."/>
    </module>
    <module name="Indentation">
      <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
      <property name="braceAdjustment" value="2"/>
      <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
      <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
      <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName">
      <property name="ignoreFinal" value="false"/>
      <property name="allowedAbbreviationLength" value="0"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, ANNOTATION_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF,
                    PARAMETER_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, METHOD_DEF, PATTERN_VARIABLE_DEF, RECORD_DEF,
                    RECORD_COMPONENT_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBeforeCaseDefaultColon"/>
    <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>
    <module name="CustomImportOrder">
      <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
      <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
      <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodParamPad">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_NEW, METHOD_CALL, METHOD_DEF,
                    SUPER_CTOR_CALL, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, RECORD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT,
                    LABELED_STAT, METHOD_REF"/>
      <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
      <property name="tokens"
               value="ANNOTATION, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CTOR_CALL, CTOR_DEF, DOT, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF,
                    EXPR, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_NEW,
                    LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_CALL,
                    METHOD_DEF, QUESTION, RESOURCE_SPECIFICATION, SUPER_CTOR_CALL, LAMBDA,
                    RECORD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
      <property name="option" value="NL"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR,
                    LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF,
                    TYPE_EXTENSION_AND "/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
      <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationMostCases"/>
      <property name="tokens"
               value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF,
                      RECORD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
      <property name="id" value="AnnotationLocationVariables"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
      <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    <module name="InvalidJavadocPosition"/>
    <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/>
    <module name="SummaryJavadoc">
      <property name="forbiddenSummaryFragments"
               value="^@return the *|^This method returns |^A [{]@code [a-zA-Z0-9]+[}]( is a )"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
    <module name="RequireEmptyLineBeforeBlockTagGroup"/>
    <module name="AtclauseOrder">
      <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
      <property name="target"
               value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="accessModifiers" value="public"/>
      <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingJavadocMethod">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="minLineCount" value="2"/>
      <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF,
                                   COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingJavadocType">
      <property name="scope" value="protected"/>
      <property name="tokens"
                value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF,
                      RECORD_DEF, ANNOTATION_DEF"/>
      <property name="excludeScope" value="nothing"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9]\w*$"/>
      <message key="name.invalidPattern"
             value="Method name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
    </module>
    <module name="SingleLineJavadoc"/>
    <module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
      <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected"/>
    </module>
    <module name="CommentsIndentation">
      <property name="tokens" value="SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT, BLOCK_COMMENT_BEGIN"/>
    </module>
    <!-- https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter -->
    <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
      <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.google.suppressionxpathfilter.config}"
             default="checkstyle-xpath-suppressions.xml" />
      <property name="optional" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder" />
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
      <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.OFF\: ([\w\|]+)" />
      <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.ON\: ([\w\|]+)" />
      <property name="checkFormat" value="$1" />
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
      <property name="commentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE.SUPPRESS\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
      <!-- $1 refers to the first match group in the regex defined in commentFormat -->
      <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
      <!-- The check is suppressed in the next line of code after the comment -->
      <property name="influenceFormat" value="1"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that this process was being run from a different directory than I thought it was.

Even though I checked to make sure the `checkstyle.xml` did indeed exist in the path that it showed, it still was breaking because my build process was failing to `cd` to the correct directory to run this!

Make sure you're running this from the place you think you are!