# gradle build with checkstyle "Unable to create a Checker" error

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm working with a `gradle` Java project where another user has enabled the `checkstyle` plugin. Unfortunately, this addition breaks our ability to build from the CLI (a'la `gradle build`). For some reason, however, we are still able to build internally in IntelliJ (2021.2 Community Ed).

I'm building with `gradle` version 4.10.2. Below is a snippet from my `build.gradle` where we enable `checkstyle`.

```
subprojects { project ->
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

...

    checkstyle {
        configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
        toolVersion '7.1.1'
    }
...
```

I've checked the compatibility guide [here](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html?hl=L%5Bg%5D;L8.12;L6.19;L5.9;L5.7-L5.5). According to this, I should be able to use this version.

Unfortunately though, my build fails when I try to `gradle build` with the following error:

```
> Task :cache:checkstyleMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cache:checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: configLocation {<REDACTED>}, classpath {<REDACTED>}.
```

Within my `checkstyle.xml`, I have the following structure:

```
<module name="Checker">

    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="150"/>
        <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
...
```

The strange thing is that when I move the `LineLength` block under `TreeWalker` as the parent, the error goes away and `checkstyle` appears to work fine from both CLI and IDE.  I got the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549449/7780575), however this change in `checkstyle` behavior should have been introduced into 8.24 and should not be required for the version I'm trying to use.

Any ideas why `checkstyle` would be behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where LineLength goes in check style file depends on the Checkstyle version. Checkstyle 8.24 and higher: directly under Checker; Checkstyle < 8.24: under TreeWalker.

As per build.gradle file, the checkstyle version used is 7.1.1

```
checkstyle {
        configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
        toolVersion '7.1.1'
    }
```